# How can I make circular Progressbar with text in center

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, progress-bar

I have to make circular `Progressbar` in Xamarin forms with the text in center and it should support both *android* and `iOS` platforms.

It would be nice if someone point me any plugin for that or control. Thank you

Comment: A similar question has been asked before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37379868/c-sharp-custom-control-circle-progress-bar-xamarin-forms but you will essentially have to make a custom renderer

Comment: @Nick - I seen this but it is not available for iOS. Thank you.

Comment: It's missing the [iOS implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573676/circular-progress-bars-in-ios) but you're still going to have to create the control individually per platform with a custom renderer

Comment: Did you checked this one : https://github.com/jsuarezruiz/MyTripCountdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Syncfusion Xamarin.Forms Progress Bar](https://www.syncfusion.com/xamarin-ui-controls/progressbar) (they have many more design options in the link).

[image]

They have a free community license for all of their controls (so long as you make under $1 million annual revenue) you can sign up for:

https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/communitylicense

And here is an example of a similar example of the implementation you are wanting to do that should get you started:

https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/progressbar/customcontent