# Oval progress bar using Xamarin Forms Shapes

Tags: xamarin.forms, progress-bar, shapes

I want to draw oval progress bar using Xamarin Forms that will look like this:[image: oval progress bar]

I found  5 years old [ProgressRingPlugin](https://github.com/AndreasHennig/ProgressRingPlugin) which seems to work as expected. However I am trying to avoid additional packages in my mobile app and also Visual Studio shows warning about this plugin (that it is not fully compatible with the project).

Please advise of how can I draw such control using standard Xamarin Forms 5. I believe it is needed to using Arc shape. Would be glad to get a solution of how to create control that is on the image using XF.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# custom control (circle progress bar) Xamarin Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37379868/c-sharp-custom-control-circle-progress-bar-xamarin-forms)

Comment: As the earlier question shows, you'll likely end up writing code very much like one of those existing plugins. Look at the ones in those answers (including the one you mentioned). Those have source code in github. If you don't want "an additional package", then the answer is to **include the source code from one of those in your project**. Then *you* are in control. Modify and maintain as desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying several solutions, I decided to implement CircleProgressBar control myself.

**CircleProgressBar.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ContentView
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="YourNamespace.Controls.CircleProgressBar">
    <Grid >

        <Path x:Name="grayPath" Stroke="LightGray" 
              StrokeThickness="4" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start">
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry>
                    <PathGeometry.Figures>
                        <PathFigureCollection>
                            <PathFigure x:Name="grayPathFigure">
                                <PathFigure.Segments>
                                    <PathSegmentCollection>
                                        <ArcSegment x:Name="grayArcSegment" SweepDirection="Clockwise" />
                                    </PathSegmentCollection>
                                </PathFigure.Segments>
                            </PathFigure>
                        </PathFigureCollection>
                    </PathGeometry.Figures>
                </PathGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>


        <Path x:Name="pathRoot" Stroke="Green" 
              StrokeThickness="4" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start">
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry>
                    <PathGeometry.Figures>
                        <PathFigureCollection>
                            <PathFigure x:Name="pathFigure">
                                <PathFigure.Segments>
                                    <PathSegmentCollection>
                                        <ArcSegment x:Name="arcSegment" SweepDirection="Clockwise" />
                                    </PathSegmentCollection>
                                </PathFigure.Segments>
                            </PathFigure>
                        </PathFigureCollection>
                    </PathGeometry.Figures>
                </PathGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>        
    </Grid>
</ContentView>
```

**CircleProgressBar.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Shapes;

namespace YourNamespace.Controls
{       
    public partial class CircleProgressBar : ContentView
    {
        public CircleProgressBar()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Angle = (Percentage * 360) / 100;
            RenderArc();
        }

        public int Radius
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(RadiusProperty); }
            set { SetValue(RadiusProperty, value); }
        }

        public Brush SegmentColor
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(SegmentColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SegmentColorProperty, value); }
        }

        public int StrokeThickness
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(StrokeThicknessProperty); }
            set { SetValue(StrokeThicknessProperty, value); }
        }

        public double Percentage
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(PercentageProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PercentageProperty, value); }
        }

        public double Angle
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(AngleProperty); }
            set { SetValue(AngleProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a BindableProperty as the backing store for Percentage.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly BindableProperty PercentageProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("Percentage", typeof(double), typeof(CircleProgressBar),
             65d, propertyChanged: OnPercentageChanged);

        // Using a BindableProperty as the backing store for StrokeThickness.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly BindableProperty StrokeThicknessProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("StrokeThickness", typeof(int), typeof(CircleProgressBar),
                5, propertyChanged: OnThicknessChanged);

        // Using a BindableProperty as the backing store for SegmentColor.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly BindableProperty SegmentColorProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("SegmentColor", typeof(Brush), typeof(CircleProgressBar),
                new SolidColorBrush(Color.Red), propertyChanged: OnColorChanged);

        // Using a BindableProperty as the backing store for Radius.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly BindableProperty RadiusProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("Radius", typeof(int), typeof(CircleProgressBar),
                25, propertyChanged: OnPropertyChanged);

        // Using a BindableProperty as the backing store for Angle.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly BindableProperty AngleProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("Angle", typeof(double), typeof(CircleProgressBar),
                120d, propertyChanged: OnPropertyChanged);

        private static void OnColorChanged(BindableObject sender, object old, object newValue)
        {
            CircleProgressBar circle = sender as CircleProgressBar;
            circle.SetColor((SolidColorBrush)newValue);
        }

        private static void OnThicknessChanged(BindableObject sender, object old, object newValue)
        {
            CircleProgressBar circle = sender as CircleProgressBar;
            circle.SetThickness((int)newValue);
        }

        private static void OnPercentageChanged(BindableObject sender, object old, object newValue)
        {
            CircleProgressBar circle = sender as CircleProgressBar;
            if (circle.Percentage > 100) circle.Percentage = 100;
            circle.Angle = (circle.Percentage * 360) / 100;
        }

        private static void OnPropertyChanged(BindableObject sender, object old, object newValue)
        {
            CircleProgressBar circle = sender as CircleProgressBar;
            circle.RenderArc();
        }

        public void SetThickness(int n)
        {
            pathRoot.StrokeThickness = n;
        }

        public void SetColor(SolidColorBrush n)
        {
            pathRoot.Stroke = n;
        }

        public void RenderSpecificArc(Path pathRoot, PathFigure pathFigure, ArcSegment arcSegment, double angle)
        {
            Point startPoint = new Point(Radius, 0);
            Point endPoint = ComputeCartesianCoordinate(angle, Radius);
            endPoint.X += Radius;
            endPoint.Y += Radius;

            pathRoot.WidthRequest = Radius * 2 + StrokeThickness;
            pathRoot.HeightRequest = Radius * 2 + StrokeThickness;
            pathRoot.Margin = new Thickness(StrokeThickness, StrokeThickness, 0, 0);


            bool largeArc = Angle > 180.0;

            Size outerArcSize = new Size(Radius, Radius);

            pathFigure.StartPoint = startPoint;

            if (startPoint.X == Math.Round(endPoint.X) && startPoint.Y == Math.Round(endPoint.Y))
                endPoint.X -= 0.01;

            arcSegment.Point = endPoint;
            arcSegment.Size = outerArcSize;
            arcSegment.IsLargeArc = largeArc;
        }

        public void RenderArc()
        {
            RenderSpecificArc(this.grayPath, this.grayPathFigure, this.grayArcSegment, angle: 360);
            RenderSpecificArc(this.pathRoot, this.pathFigure, this.arcSegment, this.Angle);            
        }

        private Point ComputeCartesianCoordinate(double angle, double radius)
        {
            // convert to radians
            double angleRad = (Math.PI / 180.0) * (angle - 90);

            double x = radius * Math.Cos(angleRad);
            double y = radius * Math.Sin(angleRad);

            return new Point(x, y);
        }
    }
}
```

You can also add bindable properties for stroke colors, thickness etc.

**Usage:**

```
<Grid>
    <controls:CircleProgressBar WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="100" Percentage="65"
    <!-- adjust margin of label depending of Circle size-->
    <Label Text="65%" FontSize="14" Margin="18,20,0,0"/>        
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `ProgressRingPlugin` is not compatible with XF 5.0,you could refer to this repo:
https://github.com/jsuarezruiz/TemplateUI#circleprogressbar

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It seems to work as expected but I am getting "Could not initialize an instance of the type 'CoreGraphics.CGPath': handle is null" on iOS. I retrieve the code only of CircleProgressBar. It is here https://gist.github.com/nrcpp/222db102fda5b7c546a5c65ed39a3079

Comment: I found that WidthRequest and HeightRequest parameters of circleprogressbar control are required to calculate radius and angle. Crash has gone, however drawing is still incorrect. I.e. Path draws outside ellipse.

Comment: Drawing algorithm does not work properly on my side. Anyway, thanks for the tip